# HD became RAW, trouble formatting to NTFS, can't install Windows

Tags: ntfs, high-definition

My grandmother's pc had some issues and wasn't booting into Windows so I was trying to fix it. I was going to make a partition to send the backup files but wasn't able to because the HD became RAW for no apparent reason. So I used a live cd, backed up the files and started to format. With Windows 7 disk I was able to delete the partition, but wasn't able to create a new one with NTFS, I tried the Windows XP disc and ditto. I finally succeeded creating a NTFS partition with a EASEUS Partition Master. I then proceeded to install Windows 7 but was unable as I couldn't select the drive.

Any thoughts of how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Use the Linux LiveCD to delete all existing partitions, then check if Windows setup sees the drive. If not, you might need to load AHCI/SATA drivers, so look for those on the manufacturer's site.

Comment: If you have trouble deleting the partitions try this from your linux live CD                 dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=10000

Comment: Hey everybody! It was not a duplicate of the thread suggested by Evereett, as I was able to create NTFS, but wasn't to install Windows. I deleted an OEM partition and everything else and created new NTFS partitions to which finally Windows 7 installed. Thank you all for trying to help!